# Generating matrices with special restriction in R

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create two randomly generated matrices which sum of the row's elements of the first matrix is equal with the sum of column's elements of the second matrix in R.
I know how to create randomly generated matrix, for exapmle:

```
     > A=matrix(rnorm(n=9, 0, 1), nrow=3, ncol=3)
     > B=matrix(rnorm(n=9, 1, 5), nrow=3, ncol=3)
```

but how can I impose this restriction when I am generating these two matrices?

Comment: You can create random numbers and distribute them to your matrices at least in random order with ``sample``.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you:

```
size <- 10
matrix_1 <- matrix(nrow = size, ncol = size)
matrix_2 <- matrix(nrow = size, ncol = size)

for (i in seq_len(size)){
  vector <- rnorm(n=size, 1, 5)
  matrix_1[i,] <- vector
  matrix_2[,i] <- sample(vector, size)

}
```

The only problem is that the second matrix is not fully random, it is a random sample of the first matrix.